# Can I Connect OVH Loadbalancer to my Kubernetes Cluster from OVH Cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, ovh

I have Kubernetes Cluster **v1.10** Over **Centos 7** Over **OVH** Cloud Provider's Servers **.**

As I knew **OVH** does not Provide **Loadbalancer**  Component Directly to **Kubernetes**

And I want to buy Loadbalancer Component From **OVH** From this **[Link](https://www.ovh.com/world/solutions/load-balancer/)**  and connect to kubernetes Cluster **.**

Can I connect Loadbalancer to Kubernetes?

And is there any tutorial?

Thank You :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can follow [this guide from OVH](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/load-balancer/loadbalancer-introduction/) in terms setting up your load balancer.

And in terms of Kubernetes you'd either want to create a [Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) exposed on a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), this is a [good tutorial](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/) for that, or you can also expose your services directly on a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) and point your load balancer's backend to all the nodes in your cluster on that specific NodePort.

I would also familiarize with the [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service) abstraction in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

How, on the other side, is not an obvious one. My suggestion would be to make it part of your kubernetes infra provisioning with terraform. Using https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/ovh/r/iploadbalancing_tcp_farm_server.html you can manage endpoints for your loadbalancer based on instances / hosts provisioned either manually or with openstack provider. That's how I do it on our OVH Kube cluster.